# Crypto++ and SHA3

Tags: implementation, sha-3, keccak

I'm using c++ with the crypto++ library, which includes the keccak algorithm for hashing. I could find instances with specific length of the hashvalues. There are  224, 256, 384 and 512 bits. But I would like to generate hashes with sha3 and specific length d - for example 1024 bits. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the library Crypto++, not a question about cryptography. However, AFAIK it does not support SHAKE (which is essentially variable length SHA-3).

Answer (score 1):

Sha3 also known as Keccak is available in 4 versions as you mentioned them. However [FIPS 202](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf) also defined SHAKE128 and SHAKE256.

While the four versions of SHA3 provide a fixed output length, SHAKE is a XOF (eXtendable Output Function), which mean that this is the one that you are interested into using in your case.

As of Crypto++, having a quick look at it unfortunately, I don't see an easy way to make it work. You could derive a base class from their SHA3 class but it won't be SHAKE due to the padding rules (if you want to follow to norms).

However because C++ is a superset of C, you can use the SHAKE implementation in C provided by the authors [here](https://github.com/gvanas/KeccakCodePackage/blob/master/Standalone/CompactFIPS202/Keccak-readable-and-compact.c) or in a more compact version [here](https://github.com/gvanas/KeccakCodePackage/blob/master/Standalone/CompactFIPS202/Keccak-more-compact.c).

Comment: I feared that this answer comes to me :-)
I located the reference implementations from the authors already - but I have there some problems:
I am not that familiar with C and C++ and importing libs, classes and so on.  So I am not able to get in run with the official implementation. So i was glad to find crypto++, which I could get to run...

Comment: I also provided you alternatives. Feel free to accept this answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: May be you can help me how to import the implementation of Keccak from the authors? I am using visual studio.

Comment: come to the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/784/the-side-channel)

Comment: The FIPS-202 padded SHA3 was only merged properly recently. Actual XOFs aren't yet natively supported, but discussion is going on right now how to do so.